# Laravel Classes and API auto Included

Tags: php, laravel

new to Laravel (coming from Java spring), while using

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return "Hello World!";
});
```

Above, we dont need to include any header files(in this and all other configuration files for LaraveL), why is this so!, as Route is in a different name-space

http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Routing.Route.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses the PHP class_alias function[1] to make some core classes available without their namespace.  There is a list of these classes used to configure the Laravel\Autoloader class in application/config/application.php in the 'aliases' option[2].

1. http://php.net/class_alias
2. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/application/config/application.php#L141-183